# Where to find VS Code Sign in and Sync?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code version: 1.45.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not able to find VS code Sign in and sync preferences.
I have looked in the preferences section and it is not listed there. Also searched it in Show all commands option.

[image]

Comment: Did you look in the Gear Icon?

Comment: yes I did and it wasn't there.